# ajax not posting to text file

Tags: php, ajax

I am learning ajax and I have followed a tutorial to post some data to a text file via a php script but I can't get it to work. Is there something I have missed.

the following is the ajax.html page which is a input text with a button to post the data via ajax

```js
<form name="testform">
  Off Min:<input name="setOffMin" type="text" id="setOffMin" maxlength="2" size="1"/></br>
  
  <button type="button" onclick="postStuff();">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="status"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function postStuff(){
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "update.php";
  var offM = document.getElementById("setOffMin").value;
  hr.open("POST", url, true);
  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
    var return_data = hr.responseText;
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
   }
  }
  hr.send(offM);
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
  
 }
</script>
```

this is the update.php file

```
 <?php

         $setOffMin = $_POST["offM"];
         $f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
         fwrite($f, $setOffMin);
         fclose($f);
 ?>
```

I have been looking over this code all last night and cannot work out why it is not writing the data to the text file.
I have run the php script editing out the $_POST and putting in a variable and it does write to the text file. So the php should work and the text file permission is correct. I expect this is the ajax that I have done wrong.
any help will be great

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files `offm` contains a string value, not a paramstring, therefore it isn't sending post params in the way you expect.

Comment: sorry not understanding you point on this. Thanks for the link i will have to have a read of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send `offM` as `urlencoded` like this:

`var offM = 'offM='+document.getElementById("setOffMin").value;`

Now when you click on Submit you call `update.php?offM=YourText` and PHP recieve var `$_POST['offM']` with value `YourText`

Comment: Thanks I can see what you are saying and it works. I was sending the data with out the variable attached. I have done this with GET and can see why the variable needs to be there but did not know how. Cheers